# Match Beamer equation size with animated Manim equation

Tags: animation, latex, beamer, manim

I am trying to animate several equations in a Beamer presentation using the [Manim](https://www.manim.community/) library. After I generate the animations, I want to include them in the presentation with exactly the same size as if I had simply generated the equation in LaTex.

For example, I might want the text `This is the Pythagorean theorem: $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$` but instead of a static equation, a^2 + b^2 = c^2 would be animated.

As I see it, there are two steps necessary that I don't know how to do yet:

1. Generate the Manim animation with dimensions that exactly match the size of "a^2 + b^2 = c^2" within the frame. This requires cropping the animation to match the size of the equation.
2. Rescale the animation when it is included in LaTeX such that the size matches the size of "a^2 + b^2 = c^2" generated by LaTeX.

For no. 2, my idea is to include `\phantom{$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$}` in LaTeX to create an empty space of the correct size for the animation, but I don't know how to get the size of the space touse as the width of the animation.

**Minimum Working Example**:

I have an Manim animation defined in a file named `main.py`:

```
from manim import *

class EquationScene(Scene):

    def construct(self):
        eq = MathTex('a^2 + b^2 = c^2', font_size=120)
        self.play(Write(eq))
```

To generate the animation, I call `manim main.py EquationScene --format=png`. I then move the PNG files into a directory named `animation` in the same directory as my TeX document, `animation.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
  This is the Pythagorean theorem: $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

  % This needs to match the size of the equation above,
  % but the scaling is wrong and there is extra whitespace
  % around the equation. The choice "width=\linewidth" is 
  % obviously wrong, but ensures the animation at least 
  % fits in the frame.
  \animategraphics[autoplay,width=\linewidth]{30}{animation/EquationScene}{0000}{0029}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```