# Crop Manim Animation to Match Content Size

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, manim

For the following Manim code, I would like to (automatically) produce an animation that only contains the equation `eq` with no empty space surrounding it. How can I accomplish this?

```
from manim import *

class EquationScene(Scene):

    def construct(self):
        eq = MathTex('a^2 + b^2 = c^2')
        self.play(Write(eq))
       
        # Crop image here, somehow?
```

If this cannot be done purely in Manim, I'm open to other approaches, such as using ImageMagick to crop the images. (The method must be automatic, however. I obviously don't want to have to manually crop every image each time I modify it.)

See also a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71824133/match-beamer-equation-size-with-animated-manim-equation/71824662#71824662).

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify that I'm interested in recording the entire animation, not just a single image.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet which will, upon rendering, produce an empty output image -- while at the same time writing a file `captured_mobject.png` in your working directory which contains the desired output.

```py
class MobjectCapture(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        mob = Text("This is some text that we would like to capture.")

        padding = 0
        m_width = mob.width + padding
        m_height = mob.height + padding
        p_width = int(m_width * config.pixel_width / config.frame_width)
        with tempconfig({
                "frame_width": m_width,
                "frame_height": m_height,
                "pixel_width": p_width,
                "pixel_height": int(p_width * m_height / m_width)
            }):
            img = mob.get_image()
            img.save("captured_mobject.png")
```

Comment: This works! But how do you save an animation?

Comment: @PaulWintz Your question was specifically about images; animations are quite a different beast. If you create the mobject outside of the class you can get its measurements in the same way, just above `MobjectCapture`. You can then also move the `tempconfig` part outside and below of the class, and then only run `MobjectCapture().render()` within the context. This will only work if your mobject does not move or changes size during the animation. If it does, I'm not sure there is an easy way of capturing it.

Comment: Is there any documentation for `tempconfig`? The only relevant page I've found is this one: https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/_modules/manim/_config.html

Comment: @PaulWintz you can pass all options to `tempconfig` that you could set in the usual config as well; see https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim._config.utils.ManimConfig.html#manim._config.utils.ManimConfig